# No handlers could be found for logger "grpc._plugin_wrapping"

Tags: python, nlp, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-language

I am getting the following error:

`No handlers could be found for logger "grpc._plugin_wrapping"` (full error text)

Similar to https://github.com/googlecodelabs/iot-data-pipeline/issues/6

We are using python2.7 and google-cloud, google-cloud-language.

Expected no error, code was previously working. Not sure as to what is the trigger. error occurs on `client.analyze_entities()`

```
from google.cloud import language
creds = {
  ...
} 
client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=creds)

 class EntityExtractionModule(BaseModule):
     """
     Extract entities from text
     """
     def __init__(self, data):
         BaseModule.__init__(self, data)

     def run(self):

        document = language.types.Document(content=full_text, language='en', type='PLAIN_TEXT',)
        r = client.analyze_entities(
          document=document,
          encoding_type='UTF32',
        )
        requests_log["entities"] = r
```